# Trying to find which text field is active ios

Tags: ios

I am trying to find which textfield is active for when the I move the view when the keyboard rises. I am trying to set a property in my viewcontroller from the subview of a scrollview.

This is the code I use to display the view in the scrollview

```
-(void)displayView:(UIViewController *)viewController{

[[viewFrame subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; 
[viewFrame scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
                        animated:NO];

[viewFrame addSubview: viewController.view];

_currentViewController = viewController;
}
```

--EDIT--

I have changed my way of thinking about this problem. Sorry for the question being ambiguous when I posted it. I was exhausted at the time and it made sense in my head.

A different but similar question: Is there a common subclass of both UITextArea and UITextView that will give me the origin of the firstResponder? Or will I have to check also the class of the firstResponder before I can find the origin?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to search for an object that has become a first responder. First responder object is the one using the keyboard (actually, it is he one having focus for user input). To check which text field uses the keyboard, iterate over your text fields (or just over all subviews) and use the `isFirstResponder` method.

EDIT:
As requested, a sample code, assuming all text fields are a subview of the view controller's view:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (view.isFirstResponder) {
        [self doSomethingCleverWithView:view];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this only iterates over the *immediate* (one level deep) children of the view controller. You will need to use a recursive approach to dig any deeper.

Answer (score 39):

I did an extension for this.

```
public extension UIResponder {

    private struct Static {
        static weak var responder: UIResponder?
    }

    public static func currentFirst() -> UIResponder? {
        Static.responder = nil
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder._trap), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        return Static.responder
    }

    @objc private func _trap() {
        Static.responder = self
    }
}
```

Use:

```
if let activeTextField = UIResponder.currentFirst() as? UITextField {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Neat! At first I was like "huh?" so in case anyone else is confused by how this works. This is from the docs for `sendAction`:

The default implementation dispatches the action method to the given target object or, if no target is specified, to the first responder

Answer (score 3):

assuming your textfields are all the same (i.e. all currency or text) and do not require any special formatting, I would suggest the following:

First, have an optional textField variable. For example:

```
var currentTextField: UITextField?
```

Then add the following:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        currentTextField = textField

}
```

Now you can do whatever you want with the 'active' text field and you do not need to track any tags unless you need some specific formatting operation.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you give all UITextfields individual Tags textfield.tag = 1

then you respond to the delegate DidBeginEditing. and check which textfield.tag is active?

Comment: Im not sure how tags actually work so currently I am not using them. I don't think this will help as the subview currently saves who is the firstResponder as a pointer, but the issue is getting that pointer the the parent of the scrollview containing the subview.

Answer (score 2):

I first used Xilexio's solution but it was slow. I ended up using tags. Here is my code and set up as an example.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentFormField;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, IOUFormField) {
    IOUFormFieldName,
    IOUFormFieldAmount,
    IOUFormFieldDescription,
    IOUFormFieldDate
};
```

...

```
self.nameField.tag = IOUFormFieldName;
self.amountField.tag = IOUFormFieldAmount;
self.descriptionField.tag = IOUFormFieldDescription;
self.dateField.tag = IOUFormFieldDate;

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Move the scroll view to a position where the user can see the top and bottom form fields
    // For example, if the user is on the description field, they should be able to see the date field and the amount field.

    // The keyboard rect value comes as a NSValue * (a wrapped NSRect) with origin and size.
    // The origin is using screen coordinates which is pixel based so don't use it.
    // Use the size. Seems like it is density based.
    CGFloat viewableScreenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;

    // When the user is on a form field, get the current form field y position to where the scroll view should move to
    CGFloat currentFormFieldYPosition = 0;
    switch (self.currentFormField) {
        case IOUFormFieldName:
        {
            currentFormFieldYPosition = self.nameField.frame.origin.y;

            // If the scroll view is at the bottom and the user taps on the name field, move the scroll view to the top.
            // This is so that users can see the give/get segments.
            [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

            break;
        }
        case IOUFormFieldAmount:
        {
            currentFormFieldYPosition = self.amountField.frame.origin.y;
            break;
        }
        case IOUFormFieldDescription:
        {
            currentFormFieldYPosition = self.descriptionField.frame.origin.y;
            break;
        }
        case IOUFormFieldDate:
        {
            currentFormFieldYPosition = self.dateField.frame.origin.y;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

    // I want the current form field y position to be 100dp from the keyboard y position.
    // 50dp for the current form field to be visible and another 50dp for the next form field so users can see it.
    CGFloat leftoverTopHeight = viewableScreenHeight - 100;

    // If the current form field y position is greater than the left over top height, that means that the current form field is hidden
    // We make the calculations and then move the scroll view to the right position
    if (currentFormFieldYPosition > leftoverTopHeight) {
        CGFloat movedScreenPosition = currentFormFieldYPosition - leftoverTopHeight;
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, movedScreenPosition) animated:YES];
    }   
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case IOUFormFieldName:
            self.currentFormField = IOUFormFieldName;
            break;
        case IOUFormFieldAmount:
            self.currentFormField = IOUFormFieldAmount;
            break;
        case IOUFormFieldDescription:
            self.currentFormField = IOUFormFieldDescription;
            break;
        case IOUFormFieldDate:
            self.currentFormField = IOUFormFieldDate;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions and I'll clarify. Note that the comments are for me. Also note that some code or omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3 use the function below function in your if else statements:

```
    if (textField.isEditing)
```

[iOS] [swift3]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Xilexio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173802/trying-to-find-which-text-field-is-active-ios#answer-12174042) but iterating over all the views to find the requested `FirstResponder` View

```
-(UIView*)getFirstResponderInView:(UIView*)parentView{
    UIView* requestedView = nil;
    for (UIView *view in parentView.subviews) {
        if (view.isFirstResponder) {
            [view resignFirstResponder];
        } else if (view.subviews.count > 0) {
            requestedView = [self getFirstResponderInView:view];
        }
        if (requestedView != nil) {
            return requestedView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Used like this :

```
UIView *view = [self getFirstResponderInView:self.view];
if(view != nil){
    [self doSomethingCleverWithView:view];
}
```