# Get current text field when keyboard was shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uitextfield

I want to get the current text field being edited when the keyboard was show. I need this to determine some y values for a frame animation. However, my keyboardWasShown method is running in the controller, so I can easily get the view but am uncertain how to get the correct text field. I have two text fields on this view.

```
//Move view to match keyboard when shown
-(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification{

    //Get frame of keyboard
    NSValue* keyboardEndFrameValue = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [keyboardEndFrameValue CGRectValue];

    //Get animation properties of keyboard
    NSNumber* animationDurationNumber = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [animationDurationNumber intValue];
    NSNumber* animationCurveNumber = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [animationCurveNumber intValue];
    UIViewAnimationOptions animationOptions = animationCurve << 16;

    //Set up animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:animationOptions animations:^{
            CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
            viewFrame.origin.y -= keyboardEndFrame.origin.y;
//I need the access to the text field here to determine y value.
            self.view.frame = viewFrame;
     } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to find which text field is active ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173802/trying-to-find-which-text-field-is-active-ios)

Comment: @Dima I want somethign like view.getCurrentlyFocusedField. With that method I'd have to go through each field and call .isFirstResponder. In addition, this is called in keyboardWillShow. Wouldn't that make the keyboard the first responder, not the text field that initiated the IBAction?

Comment: Make a property that you update each time a text field becomes active or inactive and just use that to make it simpler.

Comment: @Dima Does that mean there is no method to get the currently active UI component?

Comment: yes you can find the textfield

Comment: @BHASKAR How? Please submit some answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Delegates of your UITextField and implement your

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

create an UITextField  variable `UITextField *flagTextField;`

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
     flagTextField = textField;
}
```

Now you have the instance of textfield